# Boolean Difference not working with one specific number

Tags: mesh, boolean-modifier

I am trying to model a D20, and I am having an issue where the boolean difference seems to be creating the hole for the 7 but is not removing the top of the face of the dice. I am having no issues with any of the other numbers than the 7 so clearly it is the 7 causing the issue, but I am not sure what it is doing.

I have tried resetting the normals, deleting doubles, and finding interior faces.

Here are some screenshots of the 7.

[image]

The weird part where the lines are created is the part of the face that is not being removed

[image]

My apologies is this topic has been solved before. I tried to search and do the common issues. I know if is something with the mesh of the 7 causing this issue.

I appreciate the help!
Thanks,
Chris

tried using both fast and exact. I think it is still something wrong with the 7.

Does this work for the blender link?
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, if changing settings from fast to exact or vice versa doesn't help. thx.

Comment: As Chris it would help if you shared the file, also Boolean may create bad topology like ngons so you may need to correct manually

Comment: Hi Christopher, the first thing to try is changing the Solver in the Boolean Modifier panel. Try setting it to Fast. Sometimes applying a Boolean operation on a single face using more complex object having concave surfaces could be tricky. Try subdividing your mesh a few times to see if that helps too.

Comment: Your 7 object has overlapping vertices, select all in Edit mode and press M >Merge by Distance